# VestaCP php.ini file location in google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, vesta

I am new to google cloud and VestaCP. I need to upload a large database to the phpMyAdmin side of Vesta but the max file size limit is set to low. How do I access the `php.ini` file for Vesta?

Answer (score 0):

SSH to your server and go to etc/ folder `sudo nano php.ini` then find the `upload_max_filesize = 2M` then change the 2 to the value you want and find the `post_max_size = 8M` and change it to more than you file size, then press `ctr+x` and press `y` and restart the httpd services using `sudo service httpd restart`

Note: the file size is in MB